# Save class in array + splice deleting wrong object

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, arrays

Fiddle with html and javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/4a4u1jg1/

1. I want the elements saved in the array with the ".finished" class to be saved with the class in the array, and if I tap the element again and the class is removed, they should be saved without a class in the array, how do I accomplish this?

2a. When I double tap an item it removes the correct item on screen but after I reload the app it has removed the last item in the list instead, in other words it deletes correct from html but last item in the array. **SOLVED!**

2b. Also I can't delete a newly added item (or mark as finished) I have to re-open/update the app/browser.

```
$("li").dblclick(function()
        {
            //Removes last task instead of the task I double tapped on
            //and I can't remove newly added tasks
            taskListArray.splice($.inArray($(this), taskListArray, 1));

            $(this).remove();

            if(window.localStorage)
            {
                window.localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskListArray));
            }
        });
```

Would be awesome if someone could help me out with question #1 and #2b, thanks!

Comment: taskListArray is array of strings .... not jQuery objects. So you are looking for wrong thing using `$.inArray()`

Comment: @charlietfl Ok so what do i do? I want it to delete "this" item from array, "this" being the one I clicked on.

Comment: assuming you never sort them can use jQuery index() to get the `<li>` index instead

Comment: @charlietfl do you mean taskListArray.splice($(this).index(), taskListArray, 1); because this just adds one item named "undefined" instead of removing

Comment: `index()` is a method .... `taskListArray.splice($(this).index(),1); `

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant, my bad, fixed it, still just adds an item called "undefined" when i double click something (after i update page)

Comment: shouldn't add when you only use 2 arguments, third argument is for adding

Comment: @charlietfl OH MY, it works =O thank you so much!!!, I removed the "taskListArray" from the arguments and it fixed it. #2a solved, now i still need to fix #1 and #2b, if you know how please answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `<li>` index for your splice since the actual element is not what is in the array:

Change:

```
taskListArray.splice($.inArray($(this), taskListArray, 1));
```

To

```
taskListArray.splice($(this).index(),1);
```

Also note the third argument of splice() is for adding to array

Comment: Tried this to solve problem #1 but it doesn't work do you maybe know what i'm doing wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/2h0mhnc8/

Comment: When i tap an element it changes the class of that "li" to "finished" when i tap an element that has the class it removes the class, i want the class to be "saved" so that when i close and re-open/update the app/browser the elements that had the class will still have it and the ones that didn't wont. In other words, the elements with a line-through will still have a line-through when i update the browser.

Comment: need to store data somewhere .... if it's just for you can use localStorage...otherwise needs to be on server or cloud service like firebase